# Implement horizontal and vertical viewpager (Android)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I need to implement a viewpager that can do both horizontal and vertical paging. If the user switches the page vertically, a vertical PageTransformer should carry out the animation. Otherwise, the regular animation should happen.

I found a couple of libraries that attempt to solve this problem, but they run into problems when one of the views has a ScrollView inside.

If it's possible, I would like to implement it without third party libaries.

So far, all I have is the code for a vertical viewpager, but I can't figure out how to add the horizontal functionality as well:

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // The majority of the magic happens here
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
     */
    private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();

        float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
        float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

        ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

        return ev;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
        swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
        return intercepted;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    }

}
```

Just for reference, this is the my vertical PageTransformer:

```
public class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            view.setAlpha(1);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

            //set Y position to swipe in from top
            float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I also facing same issue in my project...:)